# Django: extend QuerySet with a default filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to implement a soft-delete model in my project. To that end, I want to be able to filter out `deleted` objects by default.

At the same time, I want to keep all my QuerySet filters in one place and accessible as `MyModel.objects`. I also want to be able to chain my filtering methods, so I'm looking towards using `MyQuerySet.as_manager()` as the manager for such models.

Thus it looks like I need to extend Django's `QuerySet`, but add a custom default filter. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

The following code does not look like a great idea.

```
class MyQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self = self.filter(deleted=False)
```

I also tried to figure out how to use `Manager.from_queryset()` for that purpose, but I still don't see how to make a manager that would be reusable, that is one that I could inherit from and be able to add my own QuerySet methods and still have the default filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by creating a custom manager

```
class SoftDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(deleted=False)
```

Create Custom Queryset to add custom queryset methods.

```
class SoftDeleteQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def soft_delete(self):
         return self.update(deleted=True)

class CarQuerySet(SoftDeleteQuerySet):
      def with_color(self):
          pass
```

In your model

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
     all_objects = models.Manager()
     objects =  SoftDeleteManager.from_queryset(CarQuerySet)()
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I can't inherit from SoftDeleteQueryset. E.g., I want models `Car` and `Driver` to be both soft-deletable, but I want the Car QuerySet to have methods `with_color`, `made_by`, and Driver — `younger_than`, `taller_than`, and want all of those methods to return only non-deleted items. With managers I won't be able to do both `Driver.objects.taller_than(1.80).younger_than(30)` and `Driver.objects.younger_than(30).taller_than(1.50)`

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.